# How to move game pieces in checkers?

Tags: unity, c#, movement, board-game

I have been creating a 3D Checkers board game via Unity.

So far, I have managed to create the board game, with its game pieces well positioned into their designated rows and tiles upon starting to play.

The only problem that I am currently facing is the diagonal movement and how my game pieces are not restricted from moving into certain tiles in the game.

I had employed a code at which my game pieces will literally levitate upon being clicked or selected to play.

However, they just linger in the air without landing on the board.

[image: Hovering piece]

Here are the codes that I have employed for two classes, namely the Board Game & the Pieces.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

### Board Game

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;


public class BoardGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Piece[,] pieces = new Piece[8, 8];
    public GameObject whitePiecePrefab;
    public GameObject blackPiecePrefab;

    private Vector3 boardOffset = new Vector3(-4.0f, 0, -4.0f);
    private Vector3 pieceOffset = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    private bool isBlack;
    private bool isBlackTurn;

    private Piece selectedPiece;


    private Vector2 mouseOver;
    private Vector2 startDrag;
    private Vector2 endDrag;




    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateBoard();
        isBlackTurn = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateMouseOver();

        {
            int x = (int)mouseOver.x;
            int y = (int)mouseOver.y;

            if (selectedPiece != null)
                UpdatePieceDrag(selectedPiece);

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                SelectPiece(x, y);

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
                TryMove((int)startDrag.x, (int)startDrag.y, x, y);

        }
    }

    private void UpdateMouseOver()
    {
      if (!Camera.main)
        {
            Debug.Log("Unable to find main camera");
            return;
        }

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition),out hit, 25.0f, LayerMask.GetMask("Board")))
        {
            mouseOver.x = (int)(hit.point.x - boardOffset.x);
            mouseOver.y = (int)(hit.point.z - boardOffset.z);

            Debug.Log(mouseOver);
        }
        else
        {
            mouseOver.x = -1;
            mouseOver.y = -1;
        }
    } 
    private void UpdatePieceDrag (Piece p)
    {
        if (!Camera.main)
        {
            Debug.Log("Unable to find main camera");
            return;
        }

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 25.0f, LayerMask.GetMask("Board")))
        {
            p.transform.position = hit.point + Vector3.up;
            
        }
    }

    private void SelectPiece(int x, int y)
    {
        //Out of Bounds
        if (x < 0 || x >= pieces.Length || y < 0 || y >= pieces.Length)
            return;

        Piece p = pieces[x, y];
        if (p != null)
        {
            selectedPiece = p;
            startDrag = mouseOver;
            Debug.Log(selectedPiece.name);

        }


    }

    private void TryMove(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        //Multiplayer Support
        startDrag = new Vector2(x1, y1);
        endDrag = new Vector2(x2, y2);
        selectedPiece = pieces[x1, y1];

        //Out of Bounds
        if (x2 < 0 || x2 >= pieces.Length || y2 < 0 || y2 >= pieces.Length)
        {
            if (selectedPiece != null)
                MovePiece(selectedPiece, x1, y1);

            startDrag = Vector2.zero;
            selectedPiece = null;
            return;
        }
        
        if (selectedPiece != null)
        {
            // If it has not moved
            if (endDrag == startDrag)
            {
                MovePiece(selectedPiece, x1, y1);
                startDrag = Vector2.zero;
                selectedPiece = null;
                return;
            }
        }
        // Check if it is a valid move
        if (selectedPiece.ValidMove(pieces, x1, y1, x2, y2))
        {
            // Did we kill anything
            // If this is a jump
            if(Mathf.Abs(x2-x2) == 2)
            {
                Piece p = pieces[(x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2];
                if(p != null)
                {
                    pieces[(x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2] = null;
                    Destroy(p);
                }

                pieces[x2, y2] = selectedPiece;
                pieces[x1, y1] = null;
                MovePiece(selectedPiece, x2, y2);

                EndTurn();

            }
        }

    }
    private void EndTurn()
    {
        selectedPiece = null;
        startDrag = Vector2.zero;

        isBlackTurn = !isBlackTurn;
        CheckVictory();

    }
    private void CheckVictory()
    {

    }

    private void GenerateBoard()
    {
        // Generate Black Team
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            bool oddRow = (y % 2 == 0);
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x += 2)
            {
                // Generate our Piece
                GeneratePiece((oddRow) ? x : x + 1 , y);
                
            }

        }

        // Generate White Team
        for (int y = 7; y > 4; y--)
        {
            bool oddRow = (y % 2 == 0);
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x += 2)
            {
                // Generate our Piece
                GeneratePiece((oddRow) ? x : x + 1, y);
            }
        }

    }

    private void GeneratePiece(int x, int y)
    {
        bool isPieceWhite = (y > 3) ? true : false;
        GameObject go = Instantiate((isPieceWhite)?whitePiecePrefab:blackPiecePrefab) as GameObject;
        go.transform.SetParent(transform);
        Piece p = go.GetComponent<Piece>();
        pieces[x, y] = p;
        MovePiece(p, x, y);
    }

    private void MovePiece(Piece p,int x, int y)
    {
        p.transform.position = (Vector3.right * x) + (Vector3.forward * y) + boardOffset + pieceOffset;
    }
    
}
```

### Pieces

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Piece : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isBlack;
    public bool isKing;

    public bool ValidMove(Piece[,] board, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        // if you are moving on top of another piece
        if (board[x2, y2] != null)
            return false;

        int deltaMove = Mathf.Abs(x1 - x2);
        int deltaMoveY = y2 - y1;

        if (isBlack || isKing)
        {
            if (deltaMove == 1)
            {
                if (deltaMoveY == 1)
                    return true;
            }
            else if(deltaMove == 2)
            {
                if (deltaMoveY == 2)
                {
                    Piece p = board[(x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2];
                    if (p != null && p.isBlack != isBlack)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!isBlack || isKing)
        {
            if (deltaMove == 1)
            {
                if (deltaMoveY == -1)
                    return true;
            }
            else if (deltaMove == 2)
            {
                if (deltaMoveY == -2)
                {
                    Piece p = board[(x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2];
                    if (p != null && p.isBlack != isBlack)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }    
}
```

Comment: [If you search for "Unity Checkers Tutorial"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+checkers+tutorial&ia=web), you will find many guides and examples of how to implement this common game in Unity. How have you tried applying this wealth of published knowledge to solve your problem? What do you need from answers here that has not already been written?

Comment: I am familiar with this video tutorial. The only difference here is that I created a 3D board game from scratch (as opposed to downloading a pre-existing 2D board game).

Comment: 3D or 2D is just a visual representation, restriction of moves dont change

Comment: Thank you for that comment Zibelas. I am fully aware of the difference. I am trying to figure out the movement of my game pieces. Upon clicking on any one of them, they levitate (however they do not land on the board). They do not follow the code instruction of moving one block diagonally, nor do they move three blocks upon killing an opponent. I seriously need help on this regard.

Comment: So is now your problem that they continue to hover after the move, that they do not move diagonal correctly or move into certain tiles (whatever that may be).

Comment: Yes exactly Zibelas. There is even one game piece that automatically moves, without having been clicked on.

Comment: If you have multiple errors in your game, fix them one by one. You could for instance ditch the whole board class and just call Trymove function directly. You can annotate it with contextmenu and call it from the editor to test if your error is in getting the wrong piece from your selector script, your evaluation script or both. Once you can reproduce your error, you can remove everything not relevant to the error and post an update of the code and tell the exact wrong behaviour and what it should do instead

Comment: I am a bit reluctant to pursue that approach Zibelas, as I can still play the game on play mode. Is it possible if we can have a virtual chat (via Microsoft Teams, Google Meet etc) for you to get a better understanding?

Comment: I'm not saying that you should get rid of them forever. But right now you have multiple sources of errors and you need to isolate them one by one. Making sure that one function is working as it should before you connect them to the next part.